# Haskell, syntactic reducing brackets

Tags: haskell, brackets, reduction

Nonsensical code I know, but trying to imprint typeclasses and so on in my brain.

Question: how do I get rid of the brackets in the following function? '$' throws an error if I use that anywhere.

```
data Vector = Vector XY XY deriving (Show)
data XY = XY (Float , Float) deriving (Show)
vector (Vector (XY (x1,y1)) (XY(x2,y2))) = [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]
```

Comment: You can only use `$` in *expressions*, since `$` is not really Haskell syntax. It is an operator that basically is a way to "trick" Haskell in adding brackets itself.

Comment: I furthermore do not see where you want to get rid of it anyway. You can pattern match with the content of `XY` instead of unpacking the tuple (and this can be more efficient), you can also remove the brackets of the `deriving`, since you only derive from one typeclass, and you can define a `pattern`.

Comment: Unless you plan on adding some instances to your `XY` type (in which case `newtype` is a more appropriate than `data` here), you could make `XY` a `type` synonym and save yourself some parentheses - `vector (Vector (x1,y1) (x2,y2)) = [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]`.

Comment: Clear! thanks for the explanations. One step further!

Comment: You don't have any type classes in your code; `Vector` and `XY` are just *types*.

Answer (score 4):

## The `$` operator

The `$` is *not* part of the Haskell syntax. It is a builtin *operator* [**`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) and the operator is defined as an `inxfixr 0` with implementation:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) f x = f x
```

So it takes as input a function `f` and a value `x`, and basically returns `f` applied to `x`. Since it has precedence `0`, that means that it binds very low, and hence if you write

```
f . g $ x + 2
```

you actually write:

```
($) ((.) f g) ((+) x 2)
```

which is a verbose form of:

```
((.) f g) ((+) x 2)
```

or:

```
(f . g) (x + 2)
```

So it can be used as a "*trick*" to force Haskell to add brackets itself. Since it is an operator, and not part of the syntax, it does not work at other locations like type signatures, patterns, deriving clauses.

The operator serves other purposes as well of course. For example we can use it in other higher-order functions (like `zipWith ($)` that takes a list of functions `[f1, f2, ...]` and a list of values `[x1, x2, ...]` and returns a list `[f1 x1, f2 x2, ...]`).

## Minizing the number of brackets

We can however minimize the amount of brackets. The `deriving` clause for example does *not* need brackets if you only derive a *single* type class, so we can write it like:

```
data Vector = Vector XY XY deriving Show
data XY = XY (Float , Float) deriving Show
```

Furthermore in the function declaration, you *unpack* the tuples, but then you *replack* the tuple elements back in a tuple that is basically the same. We can reduce the expression (and reduce the amount of unpacking and repacking) by binding with the content of the `XY` constructor instead:

```
vector (Vector (XY xy1) (XY xy2)) = [xy1, xy2]
```

Comment: Can you also mention that `$` is just function application (+ hacks that we probably shouldn't mention here)? Might not be obvious to a beginner (which is the most likely audience here).

Answer (score 2):

Using record syntax for your types,

```
data XY = XY {xy :: (Float, Float)} deriving (Show)
data Vector = Vector {v1 :: XY, v2 :: XY} deriving (Show)
```

you could write `vector` without explicit pattern matching:

```
vector :: Vector -> [(Float, Float)]
vector v = map xy [v1 v, v2 v]
```

Comment: Useful comment. The mapping over xy I don't quite grasp, but that is me being new to Haskell

Comment: It's equivalent to `[xy (v1 v), xy (v2 v)]`; it just applies `xy` to each value in the second argument.